# Invalid Argument error

Tags: magento-1.7

what is wrong with this foreach, it came with the theme but always comes up with error invalid argument, I don't do code so don't know if its a missing bit of code or missing table or what, its in the theme Helper/Data.php

```
public function getType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    if ('Mage_Catalog_Model_Product' != get_class($product) )
        return;
    foreach ($product->getOptionsType as $o) {
        $optionType = $o['type'];
        if ($optionType == 'file') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: sorry should be this

Comment: public function getType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
    {
        if ( 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Product' != get_class($product) )
            return;
        foreach ($product->getProductOptionsType() as $o) {
            $optionType = $o['type'];
            if ($optionType == 'file') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ('Mage_Catalog_Model_Product' != get_class($product) )
```

with

```
if (!($product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
```

and replace

```
foreach ($product->getOptionsType as $o) {
```

with

```
if ($product->getOptionsType()) {
    foreach ($product->getOptionsType() as $o) {
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping still getting the same error invalid argument on line 106 which is the below line

Comment: foreach ($product->getOptionsType as $o) {

Comment: see my edit. maybe it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you pass wrong type of object in getType function.

Example:

```
Mage::helper('yourmodule')->getType($object);
```

The type hint of your function is **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product**, the object you pass into getType function should be instance of **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product**

For more detail please read follow this tutorial: 
http://alanstorm.com/php_primer_type_hints